# Unable to get Client IP Address

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am trying to get ip addresses of client in WEB API . Server variable **REMOTE_ADDR** return me host address as "::1" ,What Does that mean?I am looking for IP address of client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

::1 is the ipv6 version of 127.0.0.1

It's Just one of many ways to describe the IP address of localhost in the new IPv6 version, and as was generally commented these new commands to IPv6 has its own new version and have the ping that is eventually widely used with IPv4 version, have the ping6 to be used for the IPv6 addresses